# CSS Top property not changing

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple animation that makes and element fade in and slide up, but the top property dosen't change and it only fades in(when I change it manually it dosen't work either)

My Code:

```
#login {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-top: 5px;
    -webkit-animation: slideUp 1s;
    animation: slideUp 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
    from {top: 65%; opacity: 0.2;}
    to {top: 50%; opacity: 1;}
} 


@keyframes slideUp {
    from {top: 65%; opacity: 0.2;}
    to {top: 50%; opacity: 1;}
}
```

Comment: can you share your html please? Thanks

Comment: works fine, check it out [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjjcL293/)

Comment: I tried to added a snippet here and it works in here but in my website it dosen't
If i load my html using ajax to the page with the css can it cause trouble?

Comment: show your site then

Comment: It is working fine... [fiddle](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/egJaaR)

Comment: If it works here but it doesn't work on your site, it means that problem lies somewhere else - keep digging, and update your question with additional information when you get closer to finding the actual source.

Comment: It didn't work because the parent element was absolute to..
fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to not use percent values for the position, use pixels instead.

When you position an element using percent values you position it relative to the space (width, height) that its parent element holds. In your situation the father element take no space so the 50% is 0 pixels. If the width, height are not specified an element take the space required to hold its children, but if a child is absolute positioned (your case) it take no space.